# Xcode restoring snapshot does nothing

Tags: ios, xcode, snapshot

I try to restore a snapshot and it looks like they do have my old code stored there but when I click restore, nothing changes.

I'm running the latest version of Xcode and nothing is haqppening.

Anyone know why?

Comment: What is the "latest version"?