# xCode snapshots don't appear to work

Tags: xcode, restore, snapshot

Having the same issue as this guy it seems:

[Xcode restoring snapshot does nothing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12078373/xcode-restoring-snapshot-does-nothing)

I've been creating snapshots before I try certain things and have never had to restore one.

I tried a couple of days ago and xCode presents me with the differences between the code, great.

I click restore and it says it's completed the task, however the code is the same as it was before! I now click to restore again and xCode says there is no code difference! Very frustrating and worrying if I do require a restoration!

Help!

I'm using xCode 4.6

Comment: what kind of source control are you using?  are your files on a local drive or are they on some server or somehow remote?

Comment: They're local I believe, I certainly haven't set up any remote server backups.