# Problems Using Snapshots in Xcode 5 Mac

Tags: xcode, macos, restore, snapshot

A couple of people have asked a similar question, the last one a year ago, with no solution ([Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15317812/xcode-snapshots-dont-appear-to-work) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12078373/xcode-restoring-snapshot-does-nothing)), so I thought I'd try it again.

I've created snapshots in Xcode 5.1 on a few occasions before making significant code changes. When I go to restore them, I've seen a couple of different behaviors:

1. There's one file that changed.  Xcode shows me the before and after diffs, and I say OK, and click on Restore.  The result, nothing's changed.
2. Same as one, except in this case there are multiple files that have changed.  It shows me one, and it looks good. So I click Restore.  It doesn't show me any of the *other* files diffs that have changed, and it doesn't prompt me to be sure I don't want to look at them.  After the fact, I've surmised that I need to click on each changed files in order to accept the changes.  But still, there's only one `Restore` button, which dismissed the window.  In any case, none of the files have been restored to their former state.  If I try to restore from that same snapshot again (naively thinking I could try to retrieve the other changed files), it tells me that the current state and the snapshot are the same.

If I `export` the changes to another directory, then I *do* get the reverted files.  It's when I do a `File->Restore Snapshot` where I get no results.

I've taken to manually creating zip archives of the source so I can recover the files manually.

I don't have any Source Control in use in Xcode so far. It seems I should do that if only to do periodic commits on my own.

Do other people use snapshots successfully?  Has anyone else experienced this behavior in Xcode 5?

Thanks much for your help. I've yet to get any response on the Apple Developers Forum on the topic :(

-Eric